# Select2 with checkbox not getting checked

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2, multi-select

I have the following select2 html markup:

```
<select id="industry_list" class="js-select2 form-control select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select industry..." name="industry_list[]" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
   <option value="1">Accounting</option>
   <option value="37">Administration</option>
   <option value="41">Agriculture</option>
   <option value="2">Banking and Finance</option>
</select>
```

And the following javascript to prepend a checkbox to the options:

```
window.prependCheckbox = function(data) {
   if (!data.id) {
       return data.text;
   }

   return $('<div class="checkbox no-margin">').append(
       $('<label>').append(
           $('<input type="checkbox" />').prop('checked', data.element.selected)
       ).append(data.text)
   );
};

$(function () {

   if ($(".js-select2").length === 0) {
       return;
   }

   $(".js-select2").select2({
      templateResult: prependCheckbox,
      closeOnSelect: false
   });
});
```

If i select the checkbox or the label everything works fine i.e. checkbox get checked.

But if I click the option label slightly to the right, the option still gets selected but the checkbox doesn't get checked - see image where i clicked the agriculture option where the cursor is it got selected but the checkbox did not get checked where as the other I click the checkbox or the label and checkbox get checked[image: see image]

how do i get checkbox to get checked/unchecked regardless where i click on the option?

Comment: `label` is an inline element by default, so yours will only extend as far as the width of the text demands it. Apply `display: block` to them.

Comment: *if I click the option label slightly to the right* - sounds like you're clicking *outside* the `<label>` but still inside the `<li>` (as generated by [tag:select2]).   Use the browser element inspector to view how much margin your `<label>` has.